# Android autoCompleteTextView changes with screensize?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Hello fellow Android developpers,

I have a problem regarding the autocompletetextview. I'm developping on a tablet, and I customized it nicely. When I run it on a tablet, it looks like this:
[image: Tablet view]

This is actually what I want - everything visible, small items, blue instead of orange. Cool.
And this is what happens when I run the exact same app on a smaller device, for example a Nexus-S:

[image: Nexus view]

The original views disappear, have orange stuff, and I only see one suggested item at a time or two at best. This is not what I intended.

If I run this app not in landscape, but in portrait, all works fine. Insane.
Does anybody know what I can do to keep the custom layout on the smaller screen?

Comment: So, in Nexus S itself, this runs fine on portrait mode is it? And messes up in the landscape mode huh?

Comment: Well in that case, design separate layouts for landscape and put them in the layout-land folder inside res folder.

Answer (score 1):

The second image you shown here is the result of auto complete text view or edit text when the device is in landscape mode.

If the device is in portrait mode it will display the suggestions in Vertical list, and for landscape mode it will display in horizontal list and it tries to fill the entire screen with edit text and soft keyboard.

I too faced same problem, Please check the Android Developers website for information about Supporting multiple screens, it may help you.

**New Answer**

To hide soft keyboard when you press Done button you have to use imeOptions for AutoCompleteTextView. Do these changes to your code and try it.

Changes to XML layout file as below

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:id="@+id/actv" />
```

In java file

```
        actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actv);
        actv.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    return true;    
                }
                return false;
            }           
        });
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already read and used that resource.Unfortunately I need that landscape mode, can't change to vertical, this is a specification-req. So... No matter how small I make that popup, whenever I click into the autoCompleteTextView the screen radically changes, moreover, the bloody Done button doesn't do anything by default!:)
How did you manage to solve it in the end?

Comment: @IstvanLatos means even you press Done button, the keyboard not disappearing ?